# Best way to create game application for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, game-engine

I want to create a simple scrolling game application for android and iOS, but I don't know which technologies I can use instead of create 2 projects, one for android and one for iOS. I saw a lot of technologies like unity, unreal.. but I don't know the best to use for these kind of project. Can you tell me which languages or technologies you use ?

Comment: unity is best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Unity is good for both iOS, Android and Web game.

[Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/)

and check this link

http://venturebeat.com/2014/08/20/the-top-10-engines-that-can-help-you-make-your-game/